# Trouble in a if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, logical-operators, randomaccessfile

i have some trouble to make a condition with a or . 
Look at my problem . if i execute that, it's works :

```
System.out.println(p_fileAccess.readLine().trim().startsWith("^ Item Type"));
```

//it's saying true but if i do that

```
System.out.println("data :"+(p_fileAccess.readLine().trim().startsWith("* Item Type")||p_fileAccess.readLine().trim().startsWith("^ Item Type ")));
```

it's saying false 
can you help me?

Comment: there is a white space in `startsWith("^ Item Type ")`

Comment: I assume `p_fileAccess.readLine().trim().startsWith("^ Item Type")` returns a string, else you wont be able to concatenate it with another string. So, you are applying or to strings, whats absolutely wrong.

Comment: it's the same problem

Comment: p_fileAccess.readLine().trim().startsWith("^ Item Type") does not return a boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First condition reads line #1, and second part reads again (line #2).

Try this:

```
String line = p_fileAccess.readLine().trim();
System.out.println("data:" + (line.startsWith("* Item Type") || line.startsWith("^ Item Type ")));
```

Comment: As I wrote as comment to OP: there is a white space in `startsWith("^ Item Type ")` so the second part will never be `true` (due to `trim`)

Comment: you are the real god

Comment: @StefanWarminski, file can be in format
    ^ Item Type type1  
    ^ Item Type type2  
    * Item Type type3  
so it's OK. Problem was in comparing of different lines.

Comment: @BorLaze Ok, got it. But it still will return `false` if `line` is "^ Item Type ". OP's first statement would return `true`, your solution would not.

Comment: @StefanWarminski, I guess you think, .startFrom() uses regex, like .replaceAll().

No, it uses plain string (doesn't treat it as regular expression).

Comment: No, I don't :) (assuming you wanted to post `startWith`). Try this: `"abc ".trim().startsWith("abc ")`. `trim` creates "abc" (without leading whitespace) and this does NOT start with "abc " (with leading whitespace). I edited your post to point you to the whitespace (just to find it)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming p_fileAccess is a buffered reader or similar, your second line of code is looking at two different lines in the file.  The first one does not start with "* Item Type", and the second does not start with "^ Item Type".